# How to read and perform batch processing using spring batch annotation config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-scheduled, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-stream

I have 2 different file with different data. The file contains 10K record per day.

```
Ex:
Productname price date
T shirt,500,051221
Pant,1000,051221


Productname price date
T shirt,800,061221
Pant,1800,061221
```

I want to create final output file by checking price difference by todays and yesterdays file.

```
Ex: 
Productname price 
T shirt,300
Pant,800
```

By using spring batch I have to do this.
I have tried with batch configuration by creating two different step. but its only able to read the data. but unable to
do the processing. because here I need the data of both file for processing. but in my case its reading one step after another.

Could anyone help me on this with some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to save `FlatFile` data into the database for yesterday's and today's date (may be two separate tables or in a same table if you can identify difference two records easily). Read this stored data using `JdbcCursorItemReader` or `PagingItemReader` and perform calculation/logic/massaging of data at the processor level and create a new FlatFile or save into DB as per convenience. OOTB **Spring Batch** does not provide facility to read data and perform calculation.

Suggestion - Read data from both the `FlatFile` keep it in cache and read from the cache and do the further processing.

Comment: public class YesterFileWriter implements ItemWriter<YesterdaysFile> {

 private CacheManager cacheManager;

    public YesterFileWriter (CacheManager cacheManager) {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }
    
 @Override
 public void write(List<? extends YesterdaysFile> items) throws Exception {
  cacheManager.getCache("YESTERDAYSFILE").put("listYesterdaysData", items);
  
 }
}

Comment: The above code snippet is to store data in cache, if I do this then same I will also have to do for todays file. Then Whether I need to configure another step for processing ? If yes then what needs to be done in reader, processor, writer to store final output in Database? Could you please explain this.